# Create New Rails Record without HTML Redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Rails app where I have Article and Like models.  I want someone to be able to create a Like record, similar to Facebook, where the database records the new record without redirecting them.  The two requirements I have are: create a new Like record without redirecting the user and have a flash or js message that confirms the record was created.

I tried putting this in my view.  However, when I do this, it creates two identical records:

```
<%= form_for @like, :remote=> true do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field(:article_id, :value => article.id) %>      
  <%= f.submit "Like" %>
<% end %>
```

I also, tried this which resulted in one record creating, but it took me to localhost:3000/likes:

```
<%= form_for @like do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field(:article_id, :value => article.id) %>      
  <%= f.submit "Like" %>
<% end %>
```

and then in the Like Controller commenting out the format.html and json:

```
  def create
    @like = Like.new(params[:like])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @like.save
        #  format.html { redirect_to @like, notice: 'Like was successfully created.' }
        #  format.json { render json: @like, status: :created, location: @like}
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @like.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
   end
```

What's the best way to meet my two requirements?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume Articles and Likes are related. When you want to 'like' an article you are actually updating that article, right? In other words, you would have to change the redirect within the update action of the articles controller.

P.S. I would use some javascript for submitting a form, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.edit_[here_comes_the_name] input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
      $(this).parent('form').submit();
    });
  });
</script>
```

This example submits the input from a particular form (the parent) when clicking on the check_box. Of course you would have to adjust it to fit your needs.